# .salon vs .com (.net, .org, .eu, etc...)

Tags: seo, domains, top-level-domains

Which domain would return better results in Google with search phrase "hair salon" if I hypothetically have several domains, same age with identical content, marketing and SEO?
hair.salon vs hair.* (.com, .net, .eu)

I'm building a brand, lets call it "hair".
I will buy several domains and redirect them to primary domain, but can't decide which domain to keep as primary.

Does domain extension even contribute to SEO in that way or it doesn't matter what domain extension I use and it's all about content, backlinks, marketing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that the domain extension will have any effect on SEO.

There is however another matter you need to consider: **Who operates the TLD you plan to use?**

We have had a bad experience with a `.website` domain. It was suspended by the TLD and we were unable to get in touch with the company behind the TLD to ask why it was suspended and to undo the suspension. See the [full story](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/128197/our-domain-was-suspended-by-tld-due-to-potential-abuse).

It seems to me that this company uses a completely automated system for these suspensions and they couldn't be bothered to react to unsuspension request from their customers.

You'll be much safer using one of the traditional TLDs as your primary domain. Just make sure you've done your research. Don't infringe on someones trademark, and make sure you follow all the rules.

Comment: Thanks for the input man! I'll do some research on operators.