# What actions can I take against a registrar who falsely disabled my domain for abuse?

Tags: domains, domain-registrar, icann, internet-abuse

I've seen another post about this.
[Our domain was suspended by registry due to "potential abuse"](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/128197/our-domain-was-suspended-by-registry-due-to-potential-abuse)

Last week two domains I manage were disabled due to a "breach in the registration agreement". I received no prior email correspondence about it though it says 15 days advance notice is required. My registrar is name.com and they haven't responded for a week now, the customer support says there is nothing that can be done.

Is there somewhere I can file a complaint with ICANN about the registrar?

To be clear, I'm aware of no known abuse and am responsible for securing all servers. What actions can I take?

Comment: https://www.icann.org/compliance/complaint

Comment: I assume it's a TLD under ICANN authority, so not a ccTLD, right?

Comment: yes that's correct